# How to disable Kernel Module Signing in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, module, sign

I'm working with a real time scheduler developed at my university and when I run it I get "module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel". I've learned that it might be because of some kernel module signing. Is it possible to dissable this on my ubuntu? I'm using ubuntu with VMplayer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually a developer question - you aren't trying to sign a module which you just compiled right? Ubuntu configuration is on-topic over at our sister site, AskUbuntu

Comment: @MSalters i did ask : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239225/how-to-build-from-kernel-source-via-make, noone helped

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Module signing is enabled within the kernel configuration file starting from kernel version 3.7, you can disable it by running `make menuconfig` within the kernel source directory and deselecting the `Module Signature verification` option within the `Enable loadable kernel module` menu option. After this you will have to recompile your kernel.

Comment: but how to compile it afterward? I have asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239225/how-to-build-from-kernel-source-via-make, noone answered